# Getting a certain range of memory in C++ without doing a memory copy

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a pointer of some type say a char pointer for example.

```
const char * somePtr = "hello";
```

I want to get and store the value of a certain memory range say I only want to get the word "ell" from "hello" without doing a memory copy. I can get the word "ell" by using the code below but it is using a memcpy:

```
const char * helloPtr = "hello";
char * ellPtr = new char[3];
memcpy(ellPtr, &helloPtr[1], sizeof(char) * 3);
```

Is there a way to actually get the value from a memory address without using memcpy. Something like this pseudocode:

```
char *anotherPtr = /* store the value from the memory address of helloPtr that will only get the value of "ell" */
```

I don't know if I make sense, but all my searches will lead me to do a memcpy.

Comment: What's wrong with `const char *anotherPtr = helloPtr + 1;`

Comment: @paddy It will get me the word "ello". I only wanted to get a certain range say from 1-3 only so I want the word "ell".

Comment: In C++ you can use a [std::string_view](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)

Comment: There is no such thing as "C/C++". C and C++ are very different languages. Which one are you programming in?

Comment: Or `std::span` if you're dealing with arbitrary meomry.

Comment: Sorry, yes I am programming in C++. I just wrote the pointer theory in C. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: If you ware trying to use `ell` as an ordinary null-terminated string, then the only way is to either copy it or modify the original string by terminating it at the position of the `'o'`.  However, since this is a string literal, attempting to do so is undefined behavior.  You should describe your exact requirements.  `somePtr + 1` is perfectly fine, if you know to only read 3 characters from it when you use it.

Comment: Please also note that your current solution using `memcpy` _also_ has undefined behavior if you attempt to treat it as a terminated string.  There is only enough memory for the three bytes you copied in.  It is not terminated.  Anything could come after those 3 bytes in memory.  Perhaps you're just exceptionally lucky that there was a null-byte there.  So in fact, there is absolutely no difference between accessing 3 bytes from your copied characters and accessing 3 bytes in the original string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a recent version of C++, you have tools to handle read-only spans of memory.

- Since C++17, mainly for character strings: [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view)
- Since C++20, for arbitrary memory: [`std::span`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/span)

If not, you could implement a poor's man version of those tools in C++98.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes I am dealing with arbitrary memory coming from network bytes. I know the actual location of the bytes I need but I got the problem on how to get them without copying. Thanks

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "get them".  Do you want to test if they are equal to some string?  You can compare strings without requiring null-termination.  In your question, you should describe in detail exactly what you will do with these bytes once you have "gotten them"

Comment: @paddy Oh sorry, the question is not so clear. Yes, I will compare it to strings.

Comment: You can limit your comparisons to 3 bytes.  There is no need to use terminated strings.  Since you're already using C-flavor stuff, look at `strncmp` or even `memcmp`.  Or of course, follow the great advice given in this answer.

Comment: @paddy That's answer worthy, be sure i'll upote it.

Comment: Thank you everyone. It looks like I need to implement a poor man's version of those tools mentioned or maybe it is time to shift with higher C++ version. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simply increment the pointer:

```
char * ellPtr = helloPtr + 1;
```

> It will get me the word "ello"

Just because you *can* access `ellPtr[3]` doesn't mean that you would **have** to access it.

You can refrain from accessing `ellPtr[3]` just like you would have to refrain in the case you had `memcpy`ed the range.

> Wild guess: OP would like something taking track of the slice's size

Just like in the `memcpy` case, you can store the length of the range in a variable. Alternatively, you can store the pointer past end of the range. The choice between these representations is mostly stylistic.

It will be convenient to wrap both the pointer and the size (or the other pointer) within a class. If you intend to represent a character string, then C++17 standard library already has a class for this purpose: `std::string_view`. For a non-string context, C++20 has `std::span`. If you use an older standard version, these classes are easy (easiness is highly subjective) to implement yourself.

---

If you need/want a *null terminated* substring, then your only option is to copy the substring. Or to modify the full string although that is not an option when pointing to a string literal.

Comment: @churill You can limit yourself by not accessing beyond what you want to access.

Comment: This gives me "ello". I only want a certain range say from the first up to third byte to get "ell". I used this char pointer as an example for the pointer theory. I am actually dealing with unsigned char arrays from the network.

Comment: @Louis `This gives me "ello"` See the edit.

Comment: @YSC Well, they can do that with a variable (just like if they would have to do in case they used `memcpy`).